# Proper passing information between classes c++

Tags: c++, class

I have code similar to this:

```cpp
struct InteractWithUser{
    void showInfo(){
        printf("Connected clients: %d\n", x);
    }
    
    int x;
};

struct Worker{
    InteractWithUser ui;
};

struct TCPServer{
    int connected_clients;
    Worker w;

    bool processLoop();

    InteractWithUser &getUI(){
        return w.ui;
    }
};

int main(){
    TCPServer srv;
    while(srv.processLoop()){
        // besides virtual functions,
        // this is only way I can think about it.
        srv.getUI().x = srv.connected_clients;
    }
}
```

I want to pass data between the classes, in this case, `srv.connected_clients`.

There are not just one, but several classes between `TCPServer` and `InteractWithUser`.
These classes are templated, so the exact type is not easy to know.

The only ways I can think of are:

1. `srv.getUI().x = srv.connected_clients;` inside the server loop. This includes passing things inside the server loop, which may not be ideal.
2. Pointer or reference to `srv.connected_clients` stored inside `InteractWithUser`. This could lead to disaster.
3. Abstract class and virtual methods.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Take a stroll through the Qt [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html) documentation. That is a standard pattern for decoupling classes with event handlers.

Comment: You have described your code and your solution, but what problem is it supposed to solve? What data is supposed to be passed between the objects?

Comment: Do you really need `connected_clients`? Could `auto get_connected_clients() const { return getUI().x; }` do the job?

Comment: Or, if you *have* a `connected_clients` in the server class, could the server not use `getUI().showInfo(connected_clients);` without first storing the server info in the UI class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In object-oriented programming, you often run into this pattern where:

- some state change happens in object of class `A` (e.g. `TCPServer`)
- the state of an object of class `B` (e.g. `UI`) should be changed as a result

... but you want to decouple this change of state from `A` and `B`, so that they don't have know anything about each other.
This is often done by creating an `Event` class that encapsulates this change in state and registering callbacks that respond to this event:

```cpp
// event is raised when a client connects to the server
struct ClientConnectEvent {
    int connected_clients;
    // TODO: add information about the client which has connected
};

struct TCPServer {
    int connected_clients;
    Worker w;

    std::function<void(const ClientConnectEvent&)> on_client_connect;

    // call on_client_connect() in the loop when a client connects
    bool process_loop();
};

int main() {
    TCPServer server;

    server.on_client_connect = [](const ClientConnectEvent &event) {
        // note: In the original code we got the UI from the server.
        //       That doesn't make much sense if they are meant to be decoupled.
        get_ui().text = std::to_string(event.connected_clients);
    };

    while (server.process_loop()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note a few things:

- If the callback captured something by reference, e.g. `main()::server`, then if this local object was moved or went out of scope, invoking our callback would become UB. **Be very careful with what you capture in lambdas.**
- UI frameworks often allow you registering multiple callbacks. Instead of a single `std::function`, we may store a `std::vector<std::function<...>>` or some other container.
- Some frameworks like [Qt's signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html) take this a step further:

  - *signals* are like our `on_client_connect`
  - *slots* are the receiving end in another class
  - the two can be connected directly, without a lambda expression
- Event handling can be interactive. For example, we can add a `bool canceled` to our `Event` and check the value after invoking our callback. If `true`, `TCPServer` prevents the client from connecting.

Comment: Thought about this too, but was not sure how is best way to do it without virtual methods. std::function is like virtual method itself. probably there is no other "nice" way

Comment: @Nick polymorphic classes still make sense to use over `std::function` sometimes. A `std::function` can only be invoked with one event, but communication is sometimes more complex than just "if X happens, call Y". Sometimes you have to handle "X started", and "error occurred during X", and "X finished", and it's not so good to have a separate callback for each of these. On the note of `std::function`: There isn't a much better way. Function pointers can't capture anything, and `std::move_only_function` is C++23.

Comment: check my answer if you want to see how i did proceed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it in following way:

```
struct InteractWithUser{
    void showInfo(){
        printf("Connected clients: %d\n", x);
    }
    
    void notify(int x){
       this->x = x;
    }

    int x;
};

struct Worker{
    InteractWithUser ui;

    template<typename ...Args>
    void notify(Args &&...args){
       ui.notify(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

struct TCPServer{
    int connected_clients;
    Worker w;

    bool processLoop();

    InteractWithUser &getUI(){
        return w.ui;
    }

    void connect(){
       //...
       w.notify(connected_clients);
    }

    void disconnect(){
       //...
       w.notify(connected_clients);
    }
};

int main(){
    TCPServer srv;
    while(srv.processLoop()){
    }
}
```

Using this way, I avoided both `std::function` and virtual methods.

Comment: Note that `TCPServer` and `InteractWithUser` are still coupled. `TCPServer` has a data member of type `Worker`, which has a data member of type `InteractWithUser`. It's still better than the original code, because decoupling `Worker` and `InteractWithUser` is possible quite easily, with no changes to the server.

Comment: Yes. This is correct. Server responsibility is reading from the network. Worker (probably not the best name) parses the request and pass it pass to interact with user who do the actual job.